# A word for writings about writing

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, literary-techniques

Is there a word for creating something whose subject is the same as the media used to express it. Such as:

- books about writing,
- songs about singing,
- movies about movies,

and so on?

Comment: `self-reflexive` probably?

Answer (score 3):

[Meta](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meta) seems apt here. [Oxford]

> (Of a creative work) referring to itself or to the conventions of its genre; self-referential:
>
> *the enterprise is inherently ‘meta’, since it doesn’t review movies, for example, it reviews the reviewers who review movies*

The word is quite popular. See ['Top 10 Meta Movies'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jjubGljJ3I)

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245403/how-did-meta-come-to-mean-self-referential) to know about the origin of the word.

---

You can also describe such a work as [self-referential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-referential) or [self-aware](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-awareness?q=self-%20aware#self-awareness__5). [Oxford]

Comment: I was thinking of [*metafiction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafiction) and apparently there are *metacinematic* techniques also. +1