# What does "very meta" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is part of the conversation between a detective and Nick in the movie "Gone Girl":

---

> **Detective**: *“What do you do now for work?”*
>
> **Nick**: *“My sister and I own The Bar downtown.”*
>
> **Detective**: *“Oh, The Bar? Love the name. Very meta.”*
>
> **Nick**: *“Thanks.”*

---

What does "very meta" mean?

Comment: Another related question: [How did “meta” come to mean self-referential?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245403)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definition of [meta](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/meta) -

> pertaining to or noting a story, conversation, character, etc., that
>   consciously references or comments upon its own subject or features,
>   often in the form of parody:
>
> *A movie about making a movie is just so meta—especially when the
>   actors criticize the acting.*

OR

> : showing or suggesting an explicit awareness of itself or oneself as
>   a member of its category: cleverly self-referential

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meta</sup></sup>

Something is meta (and self-referential) if it is about itself.

In your context, the detective focuses on the bar's name itself (which is ironically named "The Bar") rather than any other feature of the bar.

Another example of *meta* -

In a meeting, time spent discussing the meeting itself - how long it will last, who will talk first, whether everyone can see the screen - is meta. It's about the meeting, rather than being about the topic the meeting is supposed to be about.